# Delphi: How to set field value of a generic using RTTI?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010, rtti

I'd like to fill the field of a generic object at runtime using D2010.

```
program generic_rtti_1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  SysUtils, rtti;
type
  TMyObject = class
    FField1: string;
  end;
  TGeneric<TElement: class> = class
    procedure FillFields(Element: TElement);
  end;
procedure TGeneric<TElement>.FillFields(Element: TElement);
var
  ctx:  TRttiContext;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create();
  ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TElement)).GetField('FField1').
    SetValue(@Element, TValue.FromVariant('Some string'));
  ctx.Free();
end;
```

When the line `ctx.Free();` is executed, I get an AV at line 21986 in System.pas (function _IntfClear()). This is called from `FContextToken := nil` in rtti.pas. (In fact, the `SetValue`-induced AV pops up if I step into `SetValue`, however if step over it, only the `ctx.Free`-induced is reported. See below.)

If I remove `ctx.Free();`, the AV appears when calling `SetValue(@Element, TValue.FromVariant('Some string'));`. This too at line 21986 in System.pas.

Trying to figure this mess out, I replaced

```
ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TElement)).GetField('FField1').
  SetValue(@Element, TValue.FromVariant('Field 1 is set'));
```

with this:

```
rType := ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TElement));
rField := rType.GetField('FField1');
Val := TValue.FromVariant('Field 1 is set');
rField.SetValue(@Element, Val);
```

This time, I got no error, however `WriteLn(MyObject.FField1)` printed an empty string. (The AV re-appears if I combine `SetValue` and `TValue.FromVariant`, i.e. write `rField.SetValue(@Element, TValue.FromVariant('Field 1 is set'));`.

In order to pinpoint the guilty line, I commented out line by line, replacing the commented code with a compound statement. By accident I forgot to comment out the `Val := TValue.FromVariant('Field 1 is set');`-line above, which causes the AV to disappear once more (still calling `rField.SetValue(@Element, TValue.FromVariant('Field 1 is set'));`). (Note that I don't actually *use* `Val` in the troublesome call, still the AV disappears.)

I'm kind'a lost at this point.

For sake of completeness, here's how I'd like to use the above code:

```
var
  Generic:  TGeneric<TMyObject>;
  MyObject: TMyObject;
begin
  MyObject := TMyObject.Create();
  Generic := TGeneric<TMyObject>.Create();
  Generic.FillFields();
  WriteLn(MyObject.FField1);
  Generic.Free();
  MyObject.Free();
  ReadLn;
end;
end.
```

Do anyone know what I'm doing wrong? (Is this even possible? Are there better ways to do this using generics? )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this makes sense to you guys, but here's how I solved it. Hard cast to TObject in `procedure TGeneric<TElement>.FillFields` works like a charm. Like so:

```
ctx.GetType(TypeInfo(TElement)).GetField('FField1').
  SetValue(TObject(Element), TValue.FromVariant('Field 1 is set'));
```

Hope this is useful to someone else out there.

Comment: Of course it makes sense since SetValue takes a pointer and an object is a pointer. I think you can even go without the hardcast as long as you got the class constraint on your generic type.

Comment: @StefanGlienke Well, I did pass in the address of `Element` in my first go. Meanwhile, the constraint was `class` all the time. This did not get picked up by the compiler, so I had to start experimenting. Now, the constraint `class` basically means `TObject` - right? If you try to constrain your generics to `TObject`, you'll be nicely told that 'TObject is not a valid constraint'. So this seems to be the minimal solution.